# php session not working on link

Tags: php, session

here is the code that i am using for session.

```
<?php
    $inactive = 600;
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
    if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($session_life > $inactive)
    { 
    session_destroy();
    }

    else
    {
    echo "<script>function multiclick()
    {
    document.getElementById('Image9').style.display='none';

     }
    </script>";
    }
    }
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    ?>
```

actuly i want that when i click on link once it will be hide.but it is nor working.here is link of my page and link on that i am working is love it.
http://shoppingmore.com.hk/index.php?option=com_shopsearch&view=shopdetails&shop_id=139

please any help.thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you start session? `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }`

Comment: yes sessoin is already start on the top of the page?

Answer (score 2):

use session_start() at the top of code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $inactive = 600;
```

Comment: session is started on the top of the page.actuly i want that button disapear after once click?

Comment: when user will click love it then you just create a session for this page ($_SESSION['loved'][139] = true) where 139 is page id. Then just make a condition for love it button like - if(!$_SESSION['loved'][$shop_id]) echo 'love it';

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
session_start();

before if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) { ...
```